# How/where to generate RPG world?

Tags: java, rpg, world-design

I'm programming an RPG in java. It's text based, so movement is more or less from "room" to "room." In the case of cities, they will generally be one room, with some sub rooms for important shops and things.

I have classes for locations, but where should the programming for each individual location be done? A bad idea would be to create a bunch of New Location()s in the main method. Another idea I had was to define all of their attributes in a text file (or maybe something like JSON) and then reading it in when needed. Or should it go in a class file somewhere?

Comment: hey I think this might be a little to general / opinion based problem to warrant a formal question on the site, however seems like a perfect topic of discussion for the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Comment: Show us what you mean by classes for locations.

Comment: This is very opinion based with no right answer. The only "right" answer for this question is "Do it however works for you in your situation."

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of what _any_ right answer would be. This seems like a simple problem, but I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: @Alex My locations class so far has fields for sub-location, connected locations, NPCs contained in the location, and I might add one for events triggered in the location.

Comment: @ArtiMo Code, show some code.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is to have your content be data driven. You would store this data externally and create a class to load in the data.

There are lots of reason to do this, such as

- You don't have to recompile when your data changes
- You can use Excel or a text editor to edit the data.
- The data load can be abstracted from the data itself

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently writing a text-adventure myself and choosed the following (unoptimized, clumsy ect.) approach. Why is explained in the conclusion of the answer. For the short version, skip to the end of the answer.

My game is structured in `area`s which contain `locations`. A `player` can have `roles` which allow him to do something (or disallow him from doing so).

*Whenever a link in the following answer is mentioned, it is a ONE-WAY-Link. If two different links link each other, that may look like a two-way-link, but they are actually one-way-links which happen to point at each other.*

*When I say **type** contains **type**, I'm refering to ''contains the file name and location''. This will should be understandable from the attached pictures.*

---

## `Area`

An `area` is a folder containing four types of content. These are `exit-points`, `entry-points`, `locations` and `dungeons`.

- `exit-points` An **exit-point** contains another *areas* *entry-point* which it links to. An **exit-point** can be accessed by *locations* and *entry-points* (though later doesn't really make sense). If a player leaves a *location* through an **exit-point**, he will be transported to the *entry-point* of the linked *area*.
  An *area* can have multiple **exit-points** (imagine you leave a town (*area*) through it's east-gate (*location*) to the mountains (another *area*) or through the west-gate (*location*) to the meadows (another *area*) ).
- `entry-points` An **entry-point** contains one *location* within the same *area*. **Entry-points** can only be accessed from another *areas* *exit-point* (or from the game-engine, to drop the player in the world for the first time at game start). If a player access an **entry-point**, he is immediatly redirected to the specified *location*.
  An *area* can have multiple **entry-points** (imagine a town (*area*) where you can enter from the east-gate (*location*) or west-gate (*location*) ).
- `locations` **Locations** are folders bundling content-files (simply some .txt). A **location** has a *describing text*, an *interaction list* and at least one *location-exit-point* (and some other stuff not important for this question).
  The *describing text* is simply the text that is shown when a player enters the *location*.
  The *interaction list* contains (in a specified syntax) the reaction Y to the players action X.
  Example: **LOOK AROUND** can in one location simply display the *describing text* again. In the next location, it would trigger a change to another location (because the player fell in a trap).
  More often than not, the *describing text* already contains hints (or big signs, when it comes to this) what is possible in a **location**. If the *describing text* says there is a huge river next to the road, the player might want to **FISH**.
  If an action is not possible in a current **location**, then the default message for this command is displayed (*"You throw out your fishing pole and it lands on the ground. After a short time, you realize that without water, you can't catch anything"*).
  A *location-exit-point* is basically the same thing as an *area-exit-point*, but can only link to **locations** and *area-exit-points* inside the same *area*. This is simply to shorten path-names.
- `dungeons` These are sub-areas to have less clutter in an *area*-folder. To everything inside an *area*, they look like *locations*, but are *areas*. The only special thing is that they can have at most 1 (ONE) *entry-point*.

A little picture (sorry for my Paint-Skills):
[image: And another fruitless attempt to create something understandable in Paint.NET]

Shown is the way my linking works. Note that Entry C.B is not accessed currently. An *Entry-Point* without a corresponding *exit-point* can exist (for example for future expansions).

---

## Conclusion

The **programming** is basically done in the *interaction-list* of the *locations*. The player issues a command, the *interaction-list* says how to react to it. Of course, the possible reactions have to be coded somewhere. Up until now, I managed to do everything with static methods, because boiled down, there isn't much a player can do (look, skill, talk, leave to another location).

**WHY? WHY ALL THIS TEXT FOR SUCH A LITTLE CONLUSION?**
Valid question. I'm wrking with two non-programmers. They are responsible for the story and stuff, I do the coding. I had the choice to teach them how to programm a location, or simply read textfiles they give me. As they were somehow resistent to learning, I got stuck with the textfiles. Today, I'm happy with this.
Need a new *entry-point*? Throw in a new file with the specifications.
Another interaction, but can't edit the basefiles (because we're modding, and basefile-edits are bad!)? Throw in a new *interaction list* with a running number, because the parser only checks if the file starts with `interaction_list_`.
Add a whole new town into the landscape? Throw the *area*-folder next to the others and add some *exit-points* to the existing regions.

All in all, this might not be the best approach, but it will definitly ease your life when your world gets bigger, **because not a single line of code has to be touched anymore!**

Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: I am sorry that I had such a long run to get to the conclusion, but I got somehow carried away, and didn't want to delete it all, because I felt it makes the understanding a bit simpler. Greetings, Larethian (PS.: Potato)

Answer (score 0):

Cities are the same as the rest of your environment. How do you define it?

I think your 'rooms' are styled different - some with treasures and some with monsters. So your cities have some rooms with shops and some with parks. For me, it is the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the question is pretty vague in that it reveals nothing about your game design but here's my take on any form of "game world":

You painted a picture of this in my head ....

```
public interface IArea 
{
     public void Enter(Character newChar) { ... }
}

public class World
{
      public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City : IArea 
{
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    void Enter(Character newChar) { ... }
}

public class Room : IArea 
{
    public void Enter(Character newChar) { ... }
}
```

So in answer to your question ... 
Inherit one of these and create any custom code you need, then add your room implementations in to a city and your city implementations to a world to build your virtual world.

How you actually write the code is then entirely up to with regards to implementation details, and i'm sure you can think of many more ways to improve the IArea interface right :)